# Is the difference between directional means from two populations significant? (circular data)

Tags: linear, circular-statistics

I am comparing the orientation of two data sets with geographical lines and have used the processing tool "Linear Directional Mean" (ArcGIS Pro, Spatial Analyst) to calculate the mean of orientation.

The tool provides the directional mean, spherical variance and a test statistic.

Is it possible to compare the two means and decide if the difference is significant?

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/h-how-linear-directional-mean-spatial-statistics-w.htm

[image: Sample 1, linear directional mean]

[image: Sample 2, linear directional mean]